# Custom keyboardview in Fragment throws npe

Tags: android

I'm almost new to android dev.

I'm trying to set up a custom keyboardview inside a fragment but on "setKeyboard(..) app crashes. What am I doing wrong?
Below codes and logcat monitor. Thanks to all.

CustomKeyboard class:

```
public class CustomKeyboard {

private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private Activity mHostActivity;
private View mRootView;
private KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener;

public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, View rootView, int viewId,
                      int layoutId) {
    mHostActivity= host;
    mRootView = rootView;
    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mRootView.findViewById(viewId);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutId));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
    mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
 }
}
```

Fragment:

```
    public class FragmentGame extends ListFragment {

    private CustomKeyboard customKeyboard;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...

        //create the keyboard andd attach to keyboardview
        customKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(getActivity(), v, R.id.keyboardview,
                R.xml.keyboard);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_game_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.gontavahl.mtgsync, PID: 19983
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.setKeyboard(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.gontavahl.mtgsync.CustomKeyboard.<init>(CustomKeyboard.java:25)
                                                                       at com.gontavahl.mtgsync.FragmentGame.onCreateView(FragmentGame.java:36)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1811)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
```

Comment: What are `FragmentGame.java:36` and `CustomKeyboard.java:25`?

Comment: @IshitaSinha FragmentGame.java.36 is :  ' customKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(getActivity(), v, R.id.keyboardview,R.xml.keyboard);'

CustomKeyboard.java.25 is: 'mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutId));'

Comment: In your `onCreateView` do this:

    `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);`

Comment: @IshitaSinha i follow your advice: replacing apparently resolves npe but lead to layout error ' java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
What's changed calling inflater class instead of  previous super method? Thanks to replies

Comment: I've resolved the error by renaming listview correctly in the xml layout.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you resolved it. :)